# Animations imported into unity from blender don't work

Tags: animation, game-engine, armature, export, unity

So after decaphimes of hardwork I was ready to import my Blender character into Unity, I export my rig, model, and animation as an FBX and put it in Unity... but nothing works or plays. My Model shows up in Unity But it stays in whatever position I imported it in and nothing else, the animation plays by itself when I look at it in the Unity animator thingy on the bottom right-hand corner when I select the model. But it never applies to my character, and when ceratin animations do work it'll only work with the imported model. I'm not able to swap out animations (All animations I created that all come from the same Mama and Papa rig)is what I'm trying to say. This is a link to all of my files and assets, it would be great if someone could solve this problem for me.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eq_2D13hRwJEU_uGFt3J0UZndyesnCWj?usp=sharing

I will give whoever solves my problem boundless gratitude, thank you.

Comment: Everytime I export fbx from Blender to Unity I disable "NLA Actions" and "All Animations" options in the exporter window's animation tab. Then there will be only one animation in the file, but you can make one long animation what includes all the moves you need, then you can cut apart it in Unity. This is the only way how I can use Blender with Unity. But this works well for me.